# What is the correct way of using axios.post in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I am trying to get `axios.post` to work in `vue 3` with `laravel 8` as backend but I am getting a `POST http://localhost:3000/contact 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

This is my `vue component` (without css):

```
<template>
  <section class="contact">
    <form @submit.prevent="storeContact">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" v-model="email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Message" v-model="message">
      <button action="post" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>



<script>
import {ref} from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    let success = false;
    let error = false;
    const name = ref(null);
    const email = ref(null);
    const message = ref(null);

    function onSuccess(msg) {
      success = true;
    };

    function onFailure(msg) {
      error = true;
    };

    function storeContact() {
      axios.post('post', {
        name: 'name',
        email: 'email',
        message: 'message'
      })
        .then((res) => {
          onSuccess(res.data.message)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          onFailure(error.response.data.message)
        })
    };
    return {
      success,
      error,
      name,
      email,
      message,
      storeContact
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In addition, is there a way to use an `array` instead of `properties` inside of `axios.post` like so:

```
axios.post('post', [name, email, message]).then(...
```

Comment: An `Internal Server Error` indicates a server side error. It's possible your server is expecting the data in a specific format. What does your Laravel log show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following if You need to pass array to axios post :

```
<template>
  <section class="contact">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="user.name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" v-model="user.email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Message" v-model="user.message">
      <button @click.prevent="storeContact">Submit</button>
      <p v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>



<script>
import {ref} from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    let success = false;
    let error = '';
    const user = ref({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      massage: ''
    });

    function storeContact() {
      axios.post('Your-API-URL', Object.values(user.value))
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data)
          success = true
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          error = error.data.message
          )
        })
    };
    return {
      success,
      error,
      user,
      storeContact
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this change would help?

Comment: @tony19 Hey mate, I think that `axios.post('post'` is the source of error , maybe I'm wrong, sorry if that's the case, cheers :)

Comment: That's likely not the problem because the OP sees a `500` response. The OP was probably just using `'post'` as a placeholder in the question, just like you're using `'Your-API-URL'` in your answer.

Comment: @tony19 Ok, so like I said sorry, and what about format of data that OP post, he asked for array, maybe `Object.values(user)` will do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @NikolaPavicevic and @tony19 I was able to resolve it.

1. The `post` field was indeed a placeholder but I didn't know that it connected to the `route`. I had to change it to the corresponding route `/contact`. The error information for this was written in the `laravel logs`.
2. It is indeed possible to write the posted info inside an (array like?) object. In addition putting the code from `onSuccess` and `onFailure` directly inside the `axios` function makes it so much more readible.

This is the code now:

```
<script>
import {ref} from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    let success = false;
    let error = false;
    const user = ref({
      name: null,
      email: null,
      message: null
    });

    function storeContact() {
      axios.post('/contact', Object.values(user.value))
        .then((res) => {
          success = true
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          error = error.data.message
        })
    };

    return {
      success,
      error,
      user,
      storeContact
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Thank you so much guys! I will accept @Nikola's answer.